# Guarantee a contract can only receive one type of ERC721 nft

Tags: solidity, erc721

Creating a contract for a privateSale fo ERC721 NFTs, first I mint some inventory to the privateSale contract address implementing onErc721Received(...)
what I want to guarantee is that this privateSaleContract does only receive ERC721 tokens from one given NFT type (by its contract address)

How can I guarantee that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ERC721 standard defines two types of transfer functions:

- `safeTransferFrom()` that checks if the receiver is a contract - and if it is, tries to execute the `onERC721Received()` function on the receiver.
- But also a non-safe transfer function (`transferFrom()`) that is not supposed to call the `onERC721Received()`.

So anyone can send you NFTs using the non-safe transfer function without invoking any function on your contract. Which makes these transfers unblockable.

Comment: sure, it won't matter if they send the NFTs without safeTransferFrom because then the onERC721Received() will not be invoked, thus I will not inventory that tokenId  on my privateSale contract